# Formula to decide when to break a Certificate of Deposit (CD)?

Tags: interest-rate, comparison, certificate-of-deposit, penalty, calculation

I'm trying to create a certificate of deposit (CD) comparison tool and have been working on a formula to compare a CD with a higher interest rate to a CD I might own with a penalty period. I believe the basic formula idea:

> [image: CD Comparison]
>
> Where:
>
> - FV<sub>c</sub> = Future Value of current CD
> - CV<sub>c</sub> = Current Value of current CD (Today's value with penalty)
> - r<sub>n</sub> = The new CD's APR
> - nper<sub>n</sub> = The new CD's compounding frequency
> - n<sub>m</sub> - n<sub>t</sub> = Periods till maturity minus periods passed as of today. (The number of periods left till maturity)

This formula simplifies to:

> [image: Simplified CD Formula]
>
> Where:
>
> - r<sub>n</sub>/r<sub>c</sub>= The new/current APR
> - nper<sub>n</sub>/nper<sub>c</sub> = The new/current compounding frequency
> - n<sub>m</sub> - n<sub>t</sub> + n<sub>p</sub> = The periods till maturity minus the periods passed today plus the penalty periods of the current CD.
> - n<sub>m</sub> - n<sub>t</sub> = The periods till maturity minus the periods passed today of the new CD.

**My question is this**: This looks suspiciously close to the formula for compounding basis conversion formula at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Compounding_basis) and copied below. Can anyone help me understand the relationship between these two calculations? Additionally, is my formulation correct?

> #### Compounding basis
>
> To convert an interest rate from one compounding basis to another
> compounding basis, the following formula applies:
>
> [image: Compounding Basis]
>
> where r1 is the stated interest rate with compounding frequency n1 and
> r2 is the stated interest rate with compounding frequency n2.

Comment: Wow. That's a lot of equation for a simple concept. How about "calculate the value of current CD to maturity, then calculate the value you'd have at the same time (as the maturity) after penalty but adding new interest until then.... The math appears pretty straightforward.

Comment: I've done the one off calculations often but for instance, that calculation doesn't tell me what rates I should be looking for. Additionally the ideal rates are dependent on the day so a graph is usually more helpful.For example, plugging in the formula into [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+Y+%3D+365+*+%28%281+%2B+.0039%2F365%29%5E%28%2890+-+X+%2B+60%29%2F%2890+-+X%29%29+-+1%29+from+0+to+90) shows me that at day 50 with a 90 day CD that pays 0.39%, I need somewhere close to 1.00% for the switch to make sense. Assuming of course my calculations are correct :)

Comment: @Dilip - Not all banks impose a 3 month interest penalty for breaking a CD. For example, Ally Bank imposes a 60 day interest penalty and also offers no-penalty CDs (at a lower rate).

Comment: @Greg I mis-wrote 3 months. According to [this site](http://www.bankrate.com/brm/news/sav/20010820a.asp), Federal law mandates a minimum of seven days interest as a penalty for early withdrawal from any account classified as a time deposit (not three months as I said), and goes on to say that banks are free to, and usually do, charge a lot more. Typical charges are all interest for a thirty-day deposit, three months interest for deposits up to eighteen months, and six months for deposits of two years or more. I wonder how the no-penalty CDs avoid a violation of Federal law.

Comment: Unless you are re-inventing the wheel to create a competing product (and even if you are), why not check what your formula gives you against the [first hit on Google](http://www.depositaccounts.com/tools/break-cd-calculator.aspx) when you search for "breaking a CD"?

Comment: @Dilip - Interesting, I didn't realize a penalty was federally mandated. I found another reference to the penalty requirement [here](http://www.helpwithmybank.gov/get-answers/bank-accounts/cds-and-certificates-of-deposit/faq-bank-accounts-cds-03.html). Looking at Ally's website, it looks like they satisfy the law by requiring that you keep your no-penalty CD at least 6 days.

Comment: @Greg  And since the no-penalty CDs have a lower interest rate too, so that the customer is "paying" for the no-penalty clause for the entire duration of the deposit too.

Comment: @dilip I've used Depositaccount's calculator before but it is only useful in comparing CDs. It gives no clues as to what comparable rates would be. If you see the wolfram alpha link above you can see a chart yields richer information like how I'd need at least a doubling in rate at day 45 and at day 60 the rates needed increase significantly.

Comment: "... but it is only useful in comparing CDs."  Sorry, I misunderstood the purpose of your tool. It is the words in your first sentence "I'm trying to create a CD comparison tool" and subsequent repeated mention of CDs that is the cause of my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is this: This looks suspiciously close to the formula for
>   compounding basis conversion formula at Wikipedia and copied below.
>   Can anyone help me understand the relationship between these two
>   calculations? Additionally, is my formulation correct?

This should like the compounding basis conversion because essentially you are converting from rate 1 to rate 2 when you switch CDs.  The equation should look similar because it is a very similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note that what many people do to limit the penalty for breaking a CD is to set up a *series* of CDs, dividing the lifetime of the CD between however many there are. For example, when I briefly had some of my money in 3-month CDs running (because I needed the cash available relatively quickly and the rate on even a 3-month CD was much better than on my savings account), I started three separate CDs in successive months, renewing each when its time was up. If I had needed to break into one prematurely, I could have picked the one which would minimize the amount of interest lost.